# Can a website be made in cocos2d-html?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

I have been working with cocos2d-iPhone, cocos2d-x, and cocos2d-html5 for quite some time. I wanted to ask if it is okay to build a website with cocos2d-html5. I want to do it because I want the website look interactive, animated, and scroll around like a game. We can do this with javascript, but is it possible to write it in cocos3d-html5? What are the drawbacks of doing this? And is there any existing website that is built on cocos2d?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's certainly possible, question is whether it's advisable - and that depends on your goals. I doubt there's any website built 100% on cocos2d-html5. I wouldn't call such a thing a website anymore, it's more appropriately a web app. Common issues are the same with Flash websites: performance, memory usage, loading time, user experience, etc. etc.

Comment: possible. but I wouldn't do that if target is not for mobile only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i figured out, you cannot make a cocos2d-html based website as it is for making web apps for web sites. Although a web app can cover up the whole screen but there are a large number of issues assigned to creating such a situation. The internet users are used to using the refresh and back buttons on the web browser as well as opening in the new tab, nothing of these options would work in a cocos2d-html based web app as the navigation would be all done within the application and in no way can the button in the browser respond in the appropriate manner.